# What are the names of the video effects used in this video link

Tags: video, after-effects, premiere, editing

Here is the video link:

Below are the time stamps
1:00-1:03 
1:15
2:17-2:19

I am still quite a novice. I would like to attempt these myself, but do not know the names of the effects, which will allow me to do research and self teach.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Those are simply called glitch effects :)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Based on your answer, is there a software that you would recommend that includes these types of glitch effects?

Comment: As I only use professional grade software which don't really include such effects to dragand drop I cant help you with this question. But you can easily do it yourself in Premiere Pro, After Effects, Final Cut...